# C# OutputDataReceived to label only showing last line

Tags: c#

New to C#, so this may have an obvious answer, but right now I am stuck. I am trying to run a basic command and have the results output to either a label or a textbox. Code looks like this:

```
    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + "ping google.com")
        {
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };

        Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);
        process.OutputDataReceived += (s, a) => 
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Data))
            {
                Response.Write(a.Data + "<br />");
                Label1.Text = a.Data + Environment.NewLine;
            }
        };
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
```

The Response.Write output displays content as I'd expect it, but the Label1.Text output only shows the last line. How can I get the label text to display the full output of the command? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i wouldn't call `Process.Start` - i'd handle the event first then call `Start`.

Comment: Hint: `OutputDataReceived` isn't only called once. Your code at the moment assumes that it is.

Comment: What if you try Label1.Text +=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Label.Text = a.Data + Environment.NewLine;` is reassigning `Label.Text` every time `OutputDataRecieved` is called. If you want append to it, the solution would be:

`Label.Text += a.Data + Environment.NewLine;`

Comment: This did the trick, thank you. Was pulling my hair out yesterday trying to figure it out and I was a single character off.